# How can I fix the React Native setState error?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

First of all, I apologize for my bad English.I am using the select component of the UI Kitten. Every item fails when I change it.

This is the mistake;

"Warning cannot update during an existing state react native"

I am sharing sample codes with you.

```
const data = [
  "test 1",
  "test 2"
];

constructor(props) {
  super(props);    

  this.state = {      
    selectedIndex: new IndexPath(0), 
    displayValue: null
  };    
}

componentDidMount() {
  this._handleSetSelectedIndex = this._handleSetSelectedIndex.bind(this);
}

_handleSetSelectedIndex(value) {
  this.setState({selectedIndex: value});
}
```

in Render function;

```
<Select
  style={{ width: 300 }}
  placeholder='Default'
  value={data[this.state.selectedIndex.row]}
  selectedIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}
  onSelect={index => this._handleSetSelectedIndex(index)}>
  {data.map((key, value) => {
      return (
        <SelectItem key={value} title={key}/>
    );
  })}
</Select>
```

Comment: Not sure if it's related but you should bind methods to your class in the constructor and not in `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the program can't update state inside rendering..it goes through infinite loop so "selectedIndex" must have an event handler function to handle when to setState it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  onSelect={index => this._handleSetSelectedIndex(index)}>
```

this line seems problematic to me.

try `onSelect={this._handleSetSelectedIndex}`

also add a `console.log` inside this function and see if it ever fires when you select a new item.

Also worth to try to reproduce the basic `onSelect` first following their tutorial,

```
     <Select
        selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
        onSelect={index => setSelectedIndex(index)}>
        <SelectItem title='Option 1'/>
        <SelectItem title='Option 2'/>
        <SelectItem title='Option 3'/>
      </Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call setSelectedIndex, you pass the index, but it is the event object. Use this syntaxis:

```
onChange={(event) => this._handleSetSelectedIndex(event)}>
```

See full example in the playground: https://jscomplete.com/playground/s524798